# How to get circular shape in gridview cell in Android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I am using a gridview to make a simple calculator app. I am using gridView to hold the buttons of calculator. The gridview cell is a layout with TextView. The dextView uses a drawable background, which uses an oval shape.
Below are the XML representations:

Grid cell's layout xml

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/id_gridCell"
        android:background="@drawable/circularbutton_selector"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:text="-"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        /> </LinearLayout>
```

> 

Drawable Shape

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval">

        <solid android:color="@color/accent_material_dark"/>
        <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#AAA"/> </shape>
```

**The Question:**
Depending upon the cell width/height, the shape ends up into oval rather than circle. I can not specify a hardcoded value as the grid children should scale for any device. Is there a way to achieve circle which scales with device dimensions?
The idea is to get it scale with change in margins.

Comment: use `values-*dpi/dimens.xml` to store different size values.

Comment: I am actually looking for something that scales in between mdpi and hdpi as well so that i dont have to write it for every supported resolution. Editing the question

Comment: `something that scales in between mdpi and hdpi` Well, there's **nothing** between `mdpi` and `hdpi`! There's no `mdpi and a half`... and Harry Potter won't help here ;)

Comment: Let us say i dont want to touch XMLs again and again if i play with margins. Same screen

Comment: Then it's your problem. This is the official way - as suggested by the Android Development Team. You **could** work in code (but using pixels!!)... bleah!! what a poor code would it be. And what a **worst practice**, too!!